# Surjection of a matrix function.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be the space of all $n$ x $n$ matrices, define $T:V\rightarrow V$ as $T(A)=AB-BA$ where $A\in V$ and $B\in V$ is a fixed matrix. We are to show that

(a) $T$ is linear
(b) $T$ is not one-one
(c) $T$ is not onto

For (a), I was able to show
$T(k_1A_1+k_2A_2)=k_1T(A_1)+k_2T(A_2)   \forall A_1,A_2\in V$ and $k_1,k_2\in \Bbb R$.
Hence $T$ is linear.

For (b), I was able to show
$T(O)=T(B)=T(I_n)=O$ where $I_n$ is the $n$ x $n$ identity matrix and $O$ is the $n$ x $n$ null matrix and $I_n,O,B\in V$.
Hence $T$ is not one-one.

For (c), I need help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An endomorphism of a vector space is ono-to-one if and only if it is onto. Since you proved that it is *not* one-to-one…

You can also note that $\operatorname{tr}(AB-BA)=0$. Therefore, for instance, there is no $A$ such that $T(A)=\operatorname{Id}$.

Comment: Sir, can you please provide a source from where I might learn why an endomorphism is onto if and only if it is one-to-one.

Comment: *Any* Linear Algebra textbook proves that. For instace, it follows from the [rank-nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem): $\dim(\ker T)+\dim T(V)=\dim V$. Therefore,$$T\text{ one-to-one}\iff \ker T=\{0\}\iff T(V)=V\iff T\text{ onto.}$$

Comment: +1, but the last sentence in your answer is wrong. The OP probably meant real or complex matrices, but the trace of the identity matrix can be zero over a field of finite characteristic.

Comment: @user1551 Yes, you're right.